# MediaTrackConstraints: aspectRatio property not working on mobile brwosers

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to enforce a specific aspect ratio for an HTML video recorder using aspectRatio video constraint in a web app:

```
const videoConstraints = {
    aspectRatio: 9 / 16,
    facingMode: 'user' 
};
```

It works on desktop Chrome, but the aspect ratio doesn't apply on mobile browsers.

Is this a known limitation of mobile browsers or could there be a problem with my implementation? If it's a limitation, are there any workarounds to enforce an aspect ratio on mobile?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

The [constraints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints) you pass to [getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) (gUM) are suggestions. Many recording subsystems in devices cannot deliver precise constraints. This is especially true of aspect-ratio constraints on mobile devices, as their cameras sometimes have fixed resolutions. You give it the constraints you want, and then you either accept or reject what it gives you.

The other thing to keep in mind is that rotating the device (from upright or portrait mode to horizontal or landscape mode) changes the available constraints.

The only way I have found to beat this problem is to try different combinations. Try constraints like these if you're looking for 9/16 portrait mode.

```js
const constraints = {
  width:   {min: 360, ideal: 720, max:1440},
  height:  {min: 640, ideal:1280; max:1920}
}
```

Unfortunately, getting this stuff to work reliably takes a lot of fooling around.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yet, it's still not working on my Android's Chrome - it remains in landscape mode. Any other ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately with gUM, what you see is all you get. If you *must* use a partticular resolution of video, you can use Javascript code to copy a subset of what you capture into a bitmap, and then encode that. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70772304/whats-the-best-way-to-reduce-the-frame-rate-used-by-a-mediarecorder).